# Jquery - prevAll is unable to find element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve a simple thing: by clicking text which has a class of ".remove_summary" I want to get the value of closest previous textarea. I've been stuck with this problem for whole evening and tried .prevAll(), .closest() and .parent() methods and still get "undefined" data.
Since my DOM is a little complicated (I am using a Django framework), I made a screenshot.

[image]

After clicking red underlined text "Remove summary" I want to get the .val() of marked textarea.

My code:

```
$(".remove_summary").click(function(){
  var $txtarea = $(".remove_summary").closest('#summary').find('textarea').val();
  alert($txtarea);
});
```

});

P.S. I can not put textarea ID in the code since it is forbidden by my app's business logic. I am trying to find the closet textarea (while looking "at the top").

Could someone please explain why my code is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$(".remove_summary").click(function(){
    var $txtarea = $(this).closest('#summary').find('textarea').val();
    alert($txtarea);
});
```

or just:

```
var $txtarea = $('#summary').find('textarea').val();
```

since `id` is unique and only one `textarea` element inside your `#summary`

Your selector is not working because from the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** about `.closest()`:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

In your case, when follow the DOM tree `.remove_summary` is the child of a `<b>` tag which is the next sibling of `#summary` so `.remove_summary` paragraph is not a descendant of `#summary` div.

---

Based on your fiddle, you can do:

```
$(".remove_summary").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $txtarea = $(this).closest('b').prevAll('.summary').find('textarea').val();
    alert($txtarea);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpZN4/3/)**

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! I am starting to figure things out. But my DOM will contain a lot of similar div's with id="summary" and same "remove sumary "text inside them. My question is: how can I find the closest textarea while looking at the top of DOM from the text with class of ".remove_summary" ? I guess I need to change div's #summary id to class .summary first, because ID must be unique. And how can I find the "closest textarea at the top from text .remove_summary" then ?

Comment: Actually id is unique, you need to use class instead, then after that you can use the first option in my answer if your HTML markup is not changed.

Comment: My html markup is not changed, but unfortunately I am getting an undefined error while using the first variant of your answer. My code is a little bit messy, but could you please look at this jsfiddle ? As I said, my goal is to find the closest textarea val() at the top from text .remove_summary : http://jsfiddle.net/DpZN4/

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately JS area is empty for me, maybe I messed something? :/

Comment: Thank you! The code finally works as it should, thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because `remove_summary` is not a descendant of `summary`.

you can just use the `#summary` element because ID of an element will be unique

```
var $txtarea = $('#summary').find('textarea').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the markup in the screenshot, looks like you could use

```
$(".remove_summary").click(function(){  
   var _textarea = $(this).parent("#summary").find("textarea") .. 

}
```

*edit - missed the selector `("#summary")` sorry*

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an id, you can simply mention the id selector

```
  $('#summary').find('textarea').val();
```

An `id` should be unique in a webpage and this should find your textarea based on your markup